# Манипуляции с таблицей с помощью DOM

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! Подскажите какую-нибудь внятную ссылку, материал или свой личный небольшой пример как производить манипуляции над таблицей (тег table) на html-странице на чистом JavaScript. Под манипуляциями я понимаю считывание данных всех или одной ячейки таблицы, замена данных на новые у некоторых ячеек, перестановка столбцов и строк в таблице и поиск определенного куска текста на странице.

Comment: слабо просто доку почитать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы охватить каждую ячейку в таблице на раз, к примеру: видоизменять их в ходе построения таблицы (цвета, размер, количество ячеек и т.п.)

```
var mainTbl = document.getElementById("table_id") //получаем нашу таблицу
var tds = mainTbl.getElementsByTagName("td"); //все ячейки из таблицы

//обходим все ячейки в таблице
for(i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
   var item = tds[i];//1на из ячеек таблицы
}
```

Что бы видоизменить содержимое ячейки:

```
tds[i].innerHTML = "новое содержание";
```

Что бы добавлять ячейки:

```
mainTbl.appendChild(tds[i]);
```

Что бы удалять ячейки:

```
mainTbl.removeChild(tds[i]);
```

Что бы контролировать клики или другие манипуляции с помощью мышки, советую поинтересоваться “***событиями движений***”:
http://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-events
http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro

И можете проанализировать этот готовый пример:
http://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/9Sehg/2/